# How to draw in code an imageview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a problem. I want for each record in my core data database to draw an UIImage view on screen. But the problem is that I want to make a sort of grid. On the link below you see what I want to achieve.

[picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8050170687/in/photostream)

So my question is, how do I draw an image on screen in code. And place those images in a sort of a grid. using a collection view is no option, because the app should be running on all IOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

A quick cheat for something like this is to use a Table View and then in each cell to place another TableView but rotated at 90 degrees.

You can then use this second TableView to display the pictures etc...

This will give you a table that scrolls up and down and then each cell can scroll left to right.

I'd suggest subclassing UITableViewCell and setting it up as a UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource.

You will also have to remember to rotate the content of these "sub"tables by 90 degrees also so that they are the right way up.

This sounds like a lot of work but if you push the management of the sub Tables into the cells then it actually becomes quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

While you could implement a custom `UIView` and implement the drawRect: method and draw `UIImage`s there, I suggest just using multiple `UIImageView`s as subviews on your "main" view. Your view might be embedded in a `UIScrollView`, or you could use a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. Whichever is easier is probably related to how you can interact with the view.

Building that one huge image view is something that I'd definitely try to avoid - it costs many many (probably unnecessary) memory, and it might be slow as well. Definitely not very flexible to handle, and a pain to update dynamically.

Comment: Do you maybe have some sample code, because I don't understand it quite yet.

Comment: Sorry, no - never implemented that directly. I just want to talk you out of composing that one big view manually, as using images individually seems much more appropriate here.